# PID issues with Supervisord containers starting managed containers via shell scripts

Tags: docker, supervisord

I started a Suerpvisord container via Docker first, as follows

```
  docker run -d --name lbrain-supervisor \
    -v ${INSTALL_DIR}/supervisor/logs:/var/log/supervisor \
    -v ${INSTALL_DIR}/supervisor/supervisord.conf:/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf \
    -v ${INSTALL_DIR}/supervisor/conf.d:/etc/supervisor/conf.d \
    -v ${INSTALL_DIR}/supervisor/script:/opt/supervisor/script \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker \
    --network host \
    --privileged supervisor
```

Use Docker commands in Supervisord containers by mounting `docker.sock` and `/usr/bin/docker` on the host machine

Now for an example of a kafka program hosted by Supervisord, here is the kafka.ini configuration file

```
[program:kafka]
command=sh /opt/supervisor/script/kafka_start.sh
environment=JAVA_OPTS="-Dfastjson.parser.safeMode=true"
priority=150
autostart=false
startsecs=30
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/kafka_supervisord.log
```

You can see that he is executing a shell script named `kafka_start.sh`, let's take a look at the script

```
#!/bin/bash

if docker ps -a --filter name=lbrain-kafka -q | grep -q .; then
    docker stop lbrain-kafka && docker rm lbrain-kafka
fi

docker create -p 9092:9092 -p 19092:19092 --privileged -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -v /opt/qihoo/soc/kafka/config/kraft/server.properties:/opt/kafka/config/kraft/server.properties:ro -v /data01/entdata/kafka:/tmp/kafka-logs -e JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Duser.timezone=Aisa/Shanghai" -e KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx1g -Xms1g" --name lbrain-kafka kafka:2.13-3.5.1
exec docker start -a lbrain-kafka
```

The main thing in the script is to start the kafka container via `exec docker start -a lbrain-kafka`

There is no problem in starting the kafka container, but the problem is that when I check the status of the managed application via supervisorctl status I find that the kafka PID is not the pid of the kafka docker container

```
[root@docker02v ~]# docker exec -it lbrain-supervisor supervisorctl status
kafka                            RUNNING   pid 22, uptime 23:18:29
[root@docker02v ~]# docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' lbrain-kafka
12122
```

You can see that the kafka docker container's pid should be `12122`, but the supervisor is missing the output `22`

After troubleshooting, we found that PID 22 is actually the PID of the shell script in the Supervisor container, as follows

```
[root@docker02v ~]# docker exec -it lbrain-supervisor ps aux | grep 22
root        22  0.0  0.0 751388 26436 ?        Sl   Sep27   0:07 docker start -a
```

**How do I get the supervisorctl status output to be the container senior PID?**